# Mule 4 Xpath Expression With When Condition

Tags: xpath, mule, dataweave, mule4

I am trying to add when expression based on xml input using xpath of mule 4 #[XmlModule::xpath]
Below is my input

```
<TestAccepted xmlns="http://api.gsicommerce.com/schema/checkout/1.0"
accepted="OWD">
<Test userId="1234">
    <Name>
        <LastName>TestName</LastName>
        <FirstName>TestName</FirstName>
    </Name>        
</Test>
```

I want to add a when condition expression based on

```
#[XmlModule::xpath(//TestAccepted.@accepted == 'OWD')]
```

Kindly help on this.
My old logic on mule 3 is working. Facing difficulty to find mule 4 solution.

Comment: What's the output with : `<when expression="#[XmlModule::xpath3('//*[local-name()="TestAccepted"]/@accepted') == 'OWD']">` ?

Comment: Nops Not Working... :(

Comment: I don´t see xpath3() being mentioned in the documentation for Mule 4.

Answer (score 0):

I believe xpath is deprecated in Mule 4. Use regular mapping techniques:

```
%dw 2.0
var x=read('<TestAccepted xmlns="http://api.gsicommerce.com/schema/checkout/1.0" accepted="OWD">
<Test userId="1234">
    <Name>
        <LastName>TestName</LastName>
        <FirstName>TestName</FirstName>
    </Name>        
</Test></TestAccepted>','application/xml')
output application/json
---
{
    result: x.TestAccepted.@accepted,
    boolean: x.TestAccepted.@accepted ~= 'OWD'
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks...i have dataweave solution..But Mule 4 shared new approach for xpath https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/xml/xml-xpath

Comment: I agree but that's for connector not for dataweave.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this..

```
<when expression="#[output application/java --- XmlModule::xpath('//*[local-name()=&quot;TestAccepted&quot;]/@accepted',payload.^raw,{})[0] == 'OWD']">
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to use DataWeave instead of XPath, like in the @Alex solution. Even the [documentation of the XML Module](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/xml/xml-xpath) recommends to use DataWeave.

If you really really want to still use XPath, then you can use this expression:

```
#[XmlModule::xpath('//*[local-name()=&quot;TestAccepted&quot;]/@accepted', write(payload, 'application/xml'), {}) contains 'OWD']
```

On problem was that for some reason the payload was interpreted as an object instead of XML. I used an explicit write() to force the XML. Then the result of XmlModule::xpath() function is an array of results, so I used contains() to see if the result is in there.